# Por que esse código em python não funciona?

Tags: python-3.x

```
list = [ 1, 2, 3, [7, 8, 10, [1, 2, 3, 5]], 1, [2, 3, 9]]

for a in list:
    print(type(a))
    if type(a) == list:
        print('E lista')
```

Eu não estou entendo o porquê de não funcionar, alguém consegue me explicar?

Comment: Seu código está funcionando, só não sei o que deseja imprimir...

Comment: e para percorrer todos as listas tu deve fazer um for dentro do outro, acho que entendi o que queria, mas no caso o que fez não printa a key do array e retorna o tipo do valor que está dentro dela, no caso você está lendo o valor do array percorrido.

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo, você respondeu a minha pergunta no seu primeiro comentário. Desculpe a falta de clareza na minha dúvida.

Comment: Pedro, reverti a sua edição pq não precisa colocar "Resolvido" no título. Em vez disso, vc pode ver se alguma resposta abaixo resolveu o problema e aceitar uma delas (veja [no FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porquê fazê-lo). No caso só tem uma, mas se tivesse outras, vc poderia escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la. Se achar que nenhuma das respostas resolveu, você também pode optar por [escrever sua própria resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) e em seguida [marcar como resolvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 6):

Teu código esta funcionando, precisava apenas de alguns ajustes, vamos fazer uma analise passo-a-passo dele:

```
lista = [ 1, 2, 3, [7, 8, 10, [1, 2, 3, 5]], 1, [2, 3, 9]] # aqui tu cria tua lista de elementos

for a in lista: # define a variável "a" para cada elemento da lista
    if type(a) is list:  # verifica se algum elemento é uma lista
        print('E lista') # caso seja uma lista printa esta mensagem
    else:
        print(type(a))   # caso não seja, printa o tipo
```

1. Não é uma boa pratica colocar o nome de uma variável com o mesmo nome de um tipo.
2. Repare dentro do `if` o `is`.
3. Alterei a ordem de `print` para que ele "escolha" o que printar, se é o tipo de dado ou a mensagem (quando for uma lista).

Veja funcionando na [IDE ONE](https://ideone.com/TsqbBj)

---

EDIT.:

Caso deseja printar o que está dentro das listas internas, no teu `if` terá que fazer um outro `for`.

```
lista = [ 1, 2, 3, [7, 8, 10, [1, 2, 3, 5]], 1, [2, 3, 9]]

for a in lista:
    if type(a) is list:
        for n in a:
            print(n) # printa o valor numérico (e a lista [1, 2, 3, 5])
    else:
        print(type(a))
```

Comment: Uma correção: `if type(a) is list`, pois `type(list)` irá retornar `<class 'type'>`.

Comment: Verdade @AndersonCarlosWoss, me passei nessa kkkkkk, vou ajeitar, obrigado